# Using the Python mock module, how can I patch a class so that it stubs only the methods I want to stub and leaves other properties and methods alone?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

What I want to do is stub a couple methods in a class that gets instantiated indirectly within some code I'm testing. I'd like all other properties and methods of that patched class to function as normal.

Here's a simple case that shows what I want (Python 2.7). (Note: in my actual use case, MyClass is a class that gets instantiated indirectly within some code I'm testing):

```
from mock import patch

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.prop = 'prop'

    def foo(self):
        return 'foo'

    def bar(self):
        return 'bar'

    def unmocked(self):
        return 'unmocked'

patcher = patch('__main__.MyClass')
MockedClass = patcher.start()
instance = MockedClass.return_value
instance.foo.return_value = 'mocked foo!'
instance.bar.return_value = 'mocked bar!'

my_instance = MyClass()
assert my_instance.foo() == 'mocked foo!', my_instance.foo()
assert my_instance.bar() == 'mocked bar!', my_instance.bar()

# These asserts fail
assert my_instance.unmocked() == 'unmocked', my_instance.unmocked()
assert my_instance.prop == 'prop', my_instance.prop

patcher.stop()
```

Result:

```
$ python mock_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mock_test.py", line 27, in <module>
    assert my_instance.unmocked() == 'unmocked', my_instance.unmocked()
AssertionError: <MagicMock name='MyClass().unmocked()' id='140400215338448'>
```

Why is the `unmocked` method now returning a `MagicMock` object? How can I patch this class so it stubs only the methods I want and leave everything else alone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should patch your class using `patch.multiple`:

```
import mock

patcher = mock.patch.multiple(
    '__main__.MyClass',
    foo=mock.Mock(return_value='mocked foo!'),
    bar=mock.Mock(return_value='bar')
)
```

After updating the code with the above code it'll run and all assertions pass. Here's a full working example:

```
from mock import patch, Mock

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.prop = 'prop'

    def foo(self):
        return 'foo'

    def bar(self):
        return 'bar'

    def unmocked(self):
        return 'unmocked'

patcher = patch.multiple('__main__.MyClass',
                         foo=Mock(return_value='mocked foo!'),
                         bar=Mock(return_value='mocked bar!'))
patcher.start()

my_instance = MyClass()
assert my_instance.foo() == 'mocked foo!', my_instance.foo()
assert my_instance.bar() == 'mocked bar!', my_instance.bar()
assert my_instance.unmocked() == 'unmocked', my_instance.unmocked()
assert my_instance.prop == 'prop', my_instance.prop

patcher.stop()
```

Comment: What if I need to mock more than one method? In this case, say, `foo` and `bar` without affecting `prop`?

Comment: @klenwell: that's also possible. I have updated the answer to use `mock.patch.multiple` which allows you to patch multiple things in one call.

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me. I'll update my question to clarify this expectation.

Comment: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'return_value'

Comment: @Gang: You don't need to muddle with the `MockedClass` from my example. Just call `patcher.start()`. I've updated Simeon's answer to include complete code.

Answer (score 2):

```
from mock import patch

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.prop = 'prop'

    def foo(self):
        return 'foo'

    def bar(self):
        return 'bar'

patcher = patch.object(MyClass,"foo",return_value='mocked foo!')
MockedClass = patcher.start()


my_instance = MyClass()
assert my_instance.foo() == 'mocked foo!', my_instance.foo()

# These asserts will fail
assert my_instance.bar() == 'bar', my_instance.bar()
assert my_instance.prop == 'prop', my_instance.prop

patcher.stop()
```

You can directly mock the `method` you want instead of the whole class using `patch.object`